# Perl : Replace a string which matches the pattern

Tags: regex, perl, if-statement

I want to replace the whole string if matches the pattern at the starting of the line. My string is `$foo = "I have a dog - cat"`. 
Now if regex matches with "I have a" then string is replaced by "CHECKED"

I tried

```
$foo =~ tr /I have a/CHECKED/
```

The output is `CHECKED dog -cat` nad I don't want to add the full sentence in the regex. Like `$foo =~ /I` have a `Dog -cat/CHECKED`;

Answer (score 3):

```
$foo = "I have a dog - cat"

$foo =~ s/I have a.*/CHECKED/
```

perl command
`tr///` or `y///` for transliteration letter to letter
go https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators

Answer (score 1):

You should make the pattern match the entire string if you want the entire string to be replaced:

```
$foo =~ s/.*I have a.*/CHECKED/;
```

Alternatively, simply assign the string with a new value if it matches the pattern:

```
$foo = 'CHECKED' if $foo =~ /I have a/;
```